# phpmyadmin mysql database hosting

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect to a database set up on phpmyadmin through the MySQL workbench IDE. When attempting to load it up on the IDE it says "Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user s4905304". Any tips?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Is the MySQL server instance is running? Does the user s4905304 exist? Are you using the correct password?

Most likely this relates to the user's host. What is the host field of the user in the database, if it's `%` that won't match 'localhost' and you'll need to either modify the user or connect via TCP/IP networking instead of the socket connection. MySQL and MariaDB have different types of connections and user permissions don't apply to all of those, so you need to be careful to connect using the same connection type/host that your user was created with.